# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Swift when adding a SKSpriteNode

Tags: macos, swift, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I am creating a little game in Swift for OS X to practise but I encountered an error unkonwn to me. It appears when I try to create two new SKSpriteNodes:

```
var battleBegan:Bool = false
let beginButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button")
var backGroundMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var firstPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Pikachu", level: 25, HP: 100, power: 1)
var secondPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Aquali", level: 25, HP: 100, power: 1)
//var firstPokemonSKSN = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pikachu")
//var secondPokemonSKSN = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Aquali") //No error
```

but when I uncomment the two new SKSN:

```
var battleBegan:Bool = false
let beginButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button")
var backGroundMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var firstPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Pikachu", level: 25, HP: 100, power: 1)
var secondPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Aquali", level: 25, HP: 100, power: 1)
var firstPokemonSKSN = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pikachu") //Errors of type EXC_BAD_ACCESS
var secondPokemonSKSN = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Aquali") //Errors of type EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I am french and I understand english but explanations I found were too specific and technical for me to catch. I read I had to activate NSZombie to find my error, and that it apperas because of memory issues.

So here is my question: **Why is this error appearing when I create new SKSN, what does it mean clearly and how can I activate NSZombies in Swift to gt rid of it please ?**

Thank you !

Screenshot of the error: [image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/758626ScreenShot20140816at202953.png))</sub>

**EDIT**

After trying the breakpoint like Mike S suggested, it appears that the error appears with the AVAudioPlayer:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene
{

var battleBegan:Bool = false
let beginButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button")
var backGroundMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var firstPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Pikachu", level: 25, HP: 100, power: 1)
var secondPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Aquali", level: 25, HP: 100, power: 1)
var firstPokemonSKSN:SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pikachu")
var secondPokemonSKSN:SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Aquali")



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{

    var musicBGURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("theme", withExtension: "mp3")
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: musicBGURL, error: nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay() //BREAKPOINT Pops
    backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 0.2
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play() //BREAKPOINT Pops
    
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    
    backGroundMenu.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    backGroundMenu.size = self.frame.size
    self.addChild(backGroundMenu)
    
    beginButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    beginButton.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-CGFloat(6), duration:2)
    let action2 = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1)
    let action3 = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1)
    beginButton.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.group([action,SKAction.sequence([action2,action3])])))
    self.addChild(beginButton)
    
}
[...]
```

**Here is a [link](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/ktxj7ox8i232x/) to it**

Comment: I don't think you need to use `NSZombies` here. Are you sure `Aquali` is a valid image in the project? Any more details on the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I edited with the screenshot of the error. Yes both images were used in another project and worked without problem. I have to admit that I am a bit confused here...

Comment: Have you tried setting an "All Exceptions" break point? [Like this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions)

Comment: Yes I tried, and it stops at the AVAudioPlayer... I don't get it now. I will update the code sample

Comment: AVAudioPlayer can return nil if it doesn't initialize correctly. Try setting a breakpoint after you set backgroundMusicPlayer in didMoveToView and make sure it isn't nil.

Comment: I looked through the project you linked to and I couldn't find `theme.mp3`. If it's not in there it would cause `.URLForResource(...)` to return nil which would cause `AVAudioPlayer(...)` to return nil. Can you double-check that you have `theme.mp3` and that it's linked to in your project?

Comment: I checked and it is connected yes. The error seems to come from pikachu. Some pictures work and other don't...

Comment: I updated the [link](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/ktxj7ox8i232x/): That is very strange, depending on the image, it works or not... (look in loadBattle())

Comment: Okay. Now that I continued my [code](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/ktxj7ox8i232x/PokemonSK), the error shows up 3/4 of the time, and sometimes only it works. That is very strange, and I can't understand that...

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
var firstPokemonSKSN: SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pikachu")
```

If making the node an optional (and forcing yourself to check it for nil before using it) makes your errors go away, then you know the issue is that the (ObjC) initializer was returning nil, a situation that a plain Swift instance cannot validly handle.

For a class C {...}

```
var c: C = <blah>
```

is guaranteed to never be nil, while OTOH

```
var c: C! = <blah>
```

might be nil, but you can take a chance and not check before usage, while

```
var c: C? = <blah>
```

might be nil, and you have to check before usage like so

```
if c != nil { .. use c .. }
```

Comment: Okay, I tried this and it doesn't change anything... And what do you mean by OTOH ?

Comment: Oh, and it might be time for debugging now. You are crashed in objc_msgSend aren't you? Well then go to that frame, and helping yourself with the ABI description, figure out which selector is being called! That might be a hint on where to look next

Comment: objc_msgSend ? ABI ? that frame?

Comment: here is a [link](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/iu423a0i2e04w/) to my project if it helps you to get an idea...

Comment: I don't understand, I tested with aother images with just one it worked, but when I tried to add the second with the same workin image it doesn't work anymore --'

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I fixed it but I don't know why this work and not the other:

I just changed this

```
firstPokemonSKSN = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"pikachu")
```

by

```
firstPokemonSKSN = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: NSImage(named: "pikachu")))
```

and poof, it worked... I don't understand why, it is quite annoying. I anybody has an idea...